# I tried to import the nltk package once i installed it, but i got an error. does anyone have any idea how to fix it please

Tags: python

I installed nltk:

`!pip install nltk`

then imported it with some related functions:

```
import nltk

nltk.download('punkt')

nltk.download('stopwords')

nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

nltk.download('wordnet')

from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize 

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 

from nltk.corpus import wordnet
```

but I got this error message:

```
module 'regex.regex' has no attribute 'RegexFlag'.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this github comment](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2833#issuecomment-931969946), the issue seems to come from an outdated version of regex.

Upating the regex library to its newest version should solve the problem:

`pip install regex --upgrade`

Comment: If it solves your issue, please consider marking this question as solved by selecting this answer. It helps for the visibility of unanswered questions.